# Como poner letras en vez de números?

Tags: python

Buenos días este es mi primer comentario en este foro, ultimamente he empezado un proyecto en python que es crear mi propia competicion con la estructura de la Champions (fase de grupos y despues eliminatoria) y en la fase de grupos quiero poner algo tal que asi:

**Grupo A**

Barcelona

Liverpool

Juventus

Paris Saint-Germain

**Grupo B**

Real Madrid

Manchester City

...

He hecho por ahora esto:

```
print("\n FASE DE GRUPOS \n")

for i in range(8):
    print("Grupo")
```

Como podria poner una letra despues de la palabra grupo y que tras imprimir **Grupo A** se imprima **Grupo B** y asi hasta la **H**.

Answer (score 0):

- Puedes utilizar el módulo [string](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/string.html):

```
>>> import string
>>> print(string.ascii_uppercase)
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
>>> for i in string.ascii_uppercase:
...     print("Letter: ", i)
... 
Letter:  A
Letter:  B
Letter:  C
Letter:  D
Letter:  E
Letter:  F
Letter:  G
Letter:  H
Letter:  I
Letter:  J
Letter:  K
Letter:  L
Letter:  M
Letter:  N
Letter:  O
Letter:  P
Letter:  Q
Letter:  R
Letter:  S
Letter:  T
Letter:  U
Letter:  V
Letter:  W
Letter:  X
Letter:  Y
Letter:  Z
```

Puedes generar hasta cierta letra también haciendo un slice (desde posición de inicio hasta la posición 8: `[:8]`) de la lista:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_uppercase[:8]
'ABCDEFGH'
>>> for i in string.ascii_uppercase[:8]:
...     print("Letter ", i)
... 
Letter  A
Letter  B
Letter  C
Letter  D
Letter  E
Letter  F
Letter  G
Letter  H
```

Comment: Tu solucion no tiene en cuenta la ñ. Tu mismo lo puedes ver arriba de todo en tu respuesta.

Comment: Sí, por supuesto que no la tiene como bien indicas. Hasta la H no es necesario según lo que necesita el OP. Saludos.

Comment: Pero puede ser que necesite más letras y que llegar hasta la H sea solo un ejemplo. Quiza (por ejemplo) OP hace una consulta a una base de datos y le da grupos hasta la H, pero puede que la tabla llegue hasta la Z algún día.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Hola, @DanteS. Bueno, eso parece muy poco probable. OP dice que quiere una aplicación que simule los grupos de la Champions, los cuales son 8 (del A a la H) desde hace décadas. Además, siendo un torneo internacional, aún si deciden en algún momento aumentar los grupos, no creo que vayan a incluir un grupo nombrado con una letra del alfabeto español. Lo que quiero decir con esto es que tenemos que recordar seguir el principio YAGNI y evitar suponer cosas que no forman (y posiblemente nunca formarán) parte de los requerimientos.

Comment: Tiene sentido @revliscano

Answer (score 0):

es mas facil la solución anterior, pero tambien puedes usar esto

```
text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
for i in text:
    print("GRUPO "+i)
    if i == "H": #usado para que cuando imprima la LETRA que indique (reemplazando H) el for termine
         break
```

yo de ti no copiaba el codigo, ya que stack overflow no me dejo usar indexado por tabulador, pero aun asi puede escribirlo manualmente

Answer (score 0):

Al final tras pensarlo un rato creo que lo mejor es hacer una lista con esas letras y ponerla dependiendo de la i.

```
grupos=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
for i in range(8):
    print("Grupo", grupos[i])
```

Comment: Ya hay más de una respuesta válida indicándote cómo proceder. No hay necesidad de crear la misma con menos datos cuando ya se da a entender.